# How to Compile Google stressapptest for Android x86 Phone?

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, cross-compiling, stress-testing

**Step (1) Download Source**

```
svn checkout http://stressapptest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ stressapptest
```

**Step (2) How to Compile above Code for Android x86 Phone ?**

> Answer Not available with me.

**Step (3) How to Install ?**

```
adb push stressapptest /data/local/tmp/
adb shell chmod 777  /data/local/tmp/stressapptest
adb shell /data/local/tmp/stressapptest
```

**Step (4) How to Run ?**
    User Guide : https://code.google.com/p/stressapptest/wiki/UserGuide

**Example command lines**

```
./stressapptest -s 20 -M 256 -m 8 -C 8 -W # Allocate 256MB of memory and run 8 "warm copy" threads, and 8 cpu load threads. Exit after 20 seconds.

./stressapptest -f /tmp/file1 -f /tmp/file2 # Run 2 file IO threads, and autodetect memory size and core count to select allocated memory and memory copy threads.
```

**Question is : How to Compile above Code for Android x86 Phone ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USING Android NDK

You can compile an executable with NDK, there is an include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE) statement for your Android.mk file. (which is already included in source file).

STEPS

1. Put whole source file in jni folder(create if not exist.)
2. make Aplication.mk file.

`APP_STL := stlport_static 
APP_ABI := x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-18`

3. edit stressapptest_config_android.h file

   - Uncomment #undef STRESSAPPTEST_CPU_I686 and replace #undef with #define.
   - comment  #define STRESSAPPTEST_CPU_ARMV7A
4. compile stressapptest folder using ndk-build command.
5. in lib\x86 folder you will get **stressapptest**.
6. next step as shown in question

Comment: Working, able to run this on my x86 phone.